# Hc-05 bluetooth module pairing issue

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, hc-05

Module light is blinking/working but it's not showing for pairing in my smart phone.I have supplied it 3.3 volts and have tried different phones.[image]

Comment: what is your question? ... I do not see anything related to the Arduino in your post

Answer (score 0):

It won't pair directly you will need other apps for pairing the modules. Try using this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kai_morich.serial_bluetooth_terminal&hl=en&gl=US). It will solve your issue for sure

Comment: You can't use that app until you connect to the device through the android OS

Answer (score 0):

I put together a complete tutorial on using the HC-05 in the Arduino environment for remote programming.  You can see it [here](https://www.fpaynter.com/2019/06/arduino-remote-programming-using-a-hc-05-bluetooth-module/)

Comment: Your tutorial doesn't explain how to troubleshoot pairing problems.